# Sergen path not found

Tags: serenity-platform

I have both StartSharp and Serenity installed
I was running "dotnet sergen g" in a Serenity 5.0 project
and received the following path error
[Path Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgiDf.png)

Lines 84 and 85 in GenerateCommand.cs
`var path = Path.Combine(projectDir, name); if (File.Exists(name))`

should they be
`var path = Path.Combine(projectDir, name); if (File.Exists(path))`

or do I have another kind of problem?

Comment: Check announcement https://github.com/volkanceylan/StartSharp/issues/403 it's also gives tip about tool

Comment: fixed with https://github.com/serenity-is/Serenity/issues/5335